Why rendered Markdown cells in my Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code appears overlaid?
In my VS Code, when I open a Jupyter notebook the rendered text in Markdown cells does not appear right.
Overlaid Text in VS Code
When I double click the cell, and I am able to enter the edit mode. In this case, the text appears as normal. But when I execute the cell, the rendered text again gets overlaid. There are no such problems with the code cell.
What might be the exact issue?
I tried opening in PyCharm, there the notebook renders just fine. I have tried to create my own notebook as well, there too I am facing the same markdown cell rendering issue.

I was able to debug the issue. There was problem with this setting: "notebook.markdown.lineHeight": 1.5
Earlier, this setting used to work, I have adjusted this value to 30, and it fixes my issue.
